# Custom parameters in cross-entropy Keras

Tags: python, keras, loss, cross-entropy

I need to build custom categorical cross entropy loss function where I should compare `y_true` and `Q*y_pred` instead of just `y_pred`. `Q` is a matrix.
The problem is that the batch size must not be equal to `1`. So, there is a problem with dimensions. 
How to built categorical cross entropy loss function which works with `batch_size=200`?

For example, this is the custom categorical cross entropy loss function which works correctly but for `batch_size = 1`. 
I have 3 classes, so, the shape of `y_pred` is `(batch_size, 3, 1)` and the shape of `Q` is (3,3).
I also tried to transfer a multidimensional numpy array with `shape = (batch_size, 3, 3)` but it did not work.

```
Q=np.matrix([[0, 0.7,0.2], [0,0,0.8],[1,0.3,0]])

def alpha_loss(y_true, y_pred):         
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true,K.dot(tf.convert_to_tensor(Q,dtype=tf.float32 ),K.reshape(y_pred,(3,1)) ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using TensorFlow back end, this may work:

```
Q=np.matrix([[0, 0.7,0.2], [0,0,0.8],[1,0.3,0]])

def alpha_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   # Edit: from the comments below it appears that y_pred has dim (batch_size, 3), so reshape it to have (batch_size, 3, 1)
   y_pred = tf.expand_dims(y_pred, axis=-1)

   q_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(Q,dtype=tf.float32)

   # Changing the shape of Q from (3,3) to (batch_size, 3, 3)
   q_expanded = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(q_tf, axis=0), multiples=[tf.shape(y_pred)[0], 1,1])

   # Calculate the matrix multiplication of Q and y_pred, gives a tensor of shape (batch_size, 3, 1)
   qy_pred = tf.matmul(q_expanded, y_pred)

   return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, qy_pred)
```

Comment: thank you, it is much more better than i tried to do. ```matmul``` doesn`t work because it has matrix with 2 dimentions, not 3. but when i use ```qy_pred = tf.multiply(q_expanded, y_pred)``` it returns tensor with shape ```(batch_size, 3,3)```

Comment: You are welcome. I am not sure I understand, which bit is not working now and what did you change to obtain qy_pred of shape `(batch_size, 3, 3)`?

Comment: ```qy_pred = tf.matmul(q_expanded, y_pred)``` doesn`t work because it has matrix with 2 dimensions. but ```q_expanded``` has 3 dimensions.

Comment: `q_expanded` is meant to have 3 dimensions, which means `y_pred` only has 2. My understanding was that `y_pred` has a shape `(batch_size, 3, 1)`?

Comment: ```y_pred``` has 3 dimensions ```(batch_size, 3, 1)```. but there is error ```Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'loss_4/dense_4_loss/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [200,3,3], [?,3].```

Comment: As you can see, the error is telling you that you have 2  tensors, one with shape `[200,3,3]` and one with `[?,3]`. The first one is `q_expanded`, the second is `y_pred`. We have 2 problems: 1) The first dimension doesn't match: one has 200, the other is allocated at run time. I have edited the answer to account for this (see `tf.shape(y_pred[0])`). 2) y_pred is 2-dimensional, not 3-dimensional like you think! I have added a line to the answer to account for this. However, `y_true` may have the same problem!